# How to fast select row between dates pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I would like to know what is the most efficient way in terms of speed to select rows between two dates within the index. For example

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> index = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2030-01-02', freq='BM')
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(index), 1)), index=index)
>>> df.head()
              0
2018-01-31  0.0
2018-02-28  0.0
2018-03-30  0.0
2018-04-30  0.0
2018-05-31  0.0
```

Then one way to select all rows between e.g. `2018-05-30` `2027-07-03` is

```
>>> df.loc[(df.index >= '2018-05-30') & (df.index <= '2027-07-03')]
```

In my application I don't know upfront the values `2018-05-30` `2027-07-03`. What is (the) fastest way to achieve the desired selection?

Comment: Do you think `print (df.loc['2018-05-30':'2027-07-03'])` ? and if dont know dates for select before, how do you want select?

Comment: @jezrael The not knowing of the values was ambiguous. I meant they are not constant, i.e. changing dynamically like randomly generated each time. Is the `:` the fastest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`truncate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html):

```
print (df.truncate(before='2018-05-30', after='2027-07-03'))

print (df.loc['2018-05-30':'2027-07-03'])

print (df.loc[(df.index >= '2018-05-30') & (df.index <= '2027-07-03')])
```

**Timings**:

```
In [366]: %timeit (df.loc['2018-05-30':'2027-07-03'])
The slowest run took 5.08 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 ms per loop

In [367]: %timeit (df.loc[(df.index >= '2018-05-30') & (df.index <= '2027-07-03')])
The slowest run took 4.97 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 502 µs per loop

In [368]: %timeit (df.truncate(before='2018-05-30', after='2027-07-03'))
The slowest run took 4.98 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 450 µs per loop
```

If you change condition a bit wit not inlude last value if exist - `<=` is changed to `<`:

```
In [372]: %timeit (df.loc[(df.index >= '2018-05-31') & (df.index < '2027-05-31')])
The slowest run took 4.81 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 520 µs per loop

In [373]: %timeit (df.iloc[df.index.searchsorted('2018-05-31'): df.index.searchsorted('2027-05-31')])
10000 loops, best of 3: 136 µs per loop
```

Comment: Nice suggestion of `truncate`, I hadn't seen that approach before. Very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Your original method looks to be the faster of the two options:

**Using "&" lookup:**

```
In[]: %timeit -r 5 -n 10 df.loc[(df.index >= '2018-05-30') & (df.index <= '2027-07-03')]
Out[]: 10 loops, best of 5: 501 µs per loop
```

**Using ":" slice notation lookup:**

```
In[]: %timeit -r 5 -n 10 df.loc['2018-05-30':'2027-07-03']
Out[]: 10 loops, best of 5: 724 µs per loop
```

So you're already using an optimised operation.

EDIT: Added another slower operation to demonstrate this is already fast:

```
In[]: %timeit -r 5 -n 10 df[df.index.isin(pd.date_range("2018-05-30", "2027-07-03").values)]
Out[]: 10 loops, best of 5: 1.13 ms per loop
```

Comment: thx for your answer. do you know if there is even a feast method? maybe not using index at all but rather transform it into another format?